# Dimension of reducible polynomial with Zarisky topology

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider the set of polynomials with n variables and degree at most d.Denote this as $V_d$. This is a vector space, and consider it as an affine space by regarding the coefficients of monomials as coordinates of affine space. For example, when d=1, it is just $\mathbb A^n$. In general, when d=m, the affine space is $A^N$ where N=${d+n-1 \choose n-1}$. Let $V_{red}$ denote the set of reducible polynomials in $V_d$.

My question now is what is the dimension of the closure of $V_{red}$ in Zarisky topology of affine space? Actually $V_{red}$ can be considered as union of image of multiplication map $F_d'$:$V_{d'} \times V_{d-d'} \to V_d$, where $1<d'<d $.

All the above vector space of polynomial can be considered as some affine space, hence they are irreducible. Then I can replace the codomain of $F_{d'}$ as $C_{d'}$, the closure of image($f_{d'}$). And the fiber of $x^2$ is one-dimensional. Then $F_{d'}$ is dominant and we have dim$V_{d'}$+dim$V_{d-d'}$$\ge$C_{d'}$\ge$dim$V_{d'}$+dim$V_{d-d'}-1$. Every $C_d'$ is irreducible, since it is the closure of irreducible set. $C_{1}$ is the component that has the largest dimension among $C_{d'}$. So now the question is just what is the dimension of $C_1$, which I am looking for. Could you please help?